# ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number of iterations. warnings.warn() when performing svm

Tags: python, svm

I got this warning when performing svm. I honestly don't know what this means, so my question is what do I have to change to get rid of it. Also if there is anything that I did wrong in my code please let me know. here is my code:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

TRAIN= tweetTrainDF_nolabels
TRAIN_Labels= tweetTrainLabels
TEST= tweetTestDF
TEST_Labels= tweetTestLabels


SVM_Model1=LinearSVC(C=50)
SVM_Model1.fit(TRAIN, TRAIN_Labels)

print("SVM prediction:\n", SVM_Model1.predict(TEST))
print("Actual:")
print(TEST_Labels)

SVM_matrix = confusion_matrix(TEST_Labels, SVM_Model1.predict(TEST))
print("\nThe confusion matrix for Linear SVC C=50 is:")
print(SVM_matrix)
print("\n\n")
#--------------other kernels
## RBF
SVM_Model2=sklearn.svm.SVC(C=10, kernel='rbf', 
                           verbose=True, gamma="auto")
SVM_Model2.fit(TRAIN, TRAIN_Labels)

print("SVM prediction:\n", SVM_Model2.predict(TEST))
print("Actual:")
print(TEST_Labels)

SVM_matrix = confusion_matrix(TEST_Labels, SVM_Model2.predict(TEST))
print("\nThe confusion matrix for rbf SVM is:")
print(SVM_matrix)
print("\n\n")

## POLY
SVM_Model3=sklearn.svm.SVC(C=10, kernel='poly',degree=3,
                           gamma="auto", verbose=True)

print(SVM_Model3)
SVM_Model3.fit(TRAIN, TRAIN_Labels)
print("SVM prediction:\n", SVM_Model3.predict(TEST))
print("Actual:")
print(TEST_Labels)

SVM_matrix = confusion_matrix(TEST_Labels, SVM_Model3.predict(TEST))
print("\nThe confusion matrix for SVM poly d=2  is:")
print(SVM_matrix)
print("\n\n")
```